# Answering HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE and HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH in PHP

Tags: php, caching, header, http-headers

I have cacheable dynamic content made in PHP 5.1.0+. I already send the correct headers (including Last-Modified and ETag) to clients.

I now want my script to be able to answer `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']` when present. When the conditions matches, I want to answer a `HTTP 304 "Not Modified"` to clients.

What are the correct conditions? When exactly I issue a 304 instead of the whole content?

The accepted answer in question 
[How to know when to send a 304 Not Modified response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506/http-how-to-know-when-to-send-a-304-not-modified-response) seems to issue this correctly but I have hard times to port that code to PHP 5.

Thank you!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I've always used:

```
function caching_headers ($file, $timestamp) {
    $gmt_mtime = gmdate('r', $timestamp);
    header('ETag: "'.md5($timestamp.$file).'"');
    header('Last-Modified: '.$gmt_mtime);
    header('Cache-Control: public');

    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'])) {
        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] == $gmt_mtime || str_replace('"', '', stripslashes($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'])) == md5($timestamp.$file)) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't remember whether I wrote it or got it from somewhere else...

I'm normally using it at the top of a file in this way:

```
caching_headers ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], filemtime($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
```

Comment: Nice function Rich! A little more legible: `caching_headers (__FILE__, filemtime(__FILE__));`.

Comment: Really helpful! Tried this but performing multiple requests give out alternatively a 200 and 304. Moving the "Last-Modified" and "Cache-Control" after the "ETag" definition fixes it.

Comment: Would be good to check if `"HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH"` was set as well to avoid PHP warning and PHP unknown when null is passed to stripslashes in PHP 8.1.

Answer (score 3):

The answer you're referencing seems to contain all you need. To summarize:

- generate your own ETag and Last-Modified headers, just as if you would be sending the whole body
- look at the If-Modified-Since header the client sent, if your own last-modified is older or the same send the 304
- look at the If-None-Match header of the client, if it matches your own ETag send the 304
- if you reach this place, the headers did not match, send complete body and new ETag/Last-Modified headers

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet of my render_file() function.

```
$last_modified = filemtime($filename);
if ($last_modified === false) {
  throw new Exception('Modify date unknown');
}
if (array_key_exists('HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE', $_SERVER)) {
  $if_modified_since = strtotime(preg_replace('/;.*$/', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']));
  if ($if_modified_since >= $last_modified) { // Is the Cached version the most recent?
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 304 Not Modified');
    exit();
  }
}
header('Last-Modified: '.date('r', $last_modified)); // tz should be GMT according to specs but also works with other tzs

// other headers and contents go here
```

Comment: And what about HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH? Where whould it be fitted in your snippet?

Comment: The modification-date was validation enough for me, calculating a Etag (checksum for the contents md5/sha1) generates some server-overhead. However, etags are less errorprone.
If content correctness is important check the IF_NONE_MATCH first.
If the IF_NONE_MATCH isn't set, then check the IF_MODIFIED_SINCE.
Dont check the IF_MODIFIED_SINCE if the etag doesnt match. Because you know the browser cache is invalid! Just send the 304 header and exit()

Answer (score 1):

If I could improve slightly on the original brilliant answer from Rich Bradshaw https://stackoverflow.com/users/16511/rich-bradshaw

This code is tweaked and now 100% passes the If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match checks. It also correctly formats the Last-Modified Date as original answer sends out +0000 on the end instead of GMT and adds the VARY header to the 304 response. You can test this at redbot.org

```
<?php
function caching_headers ($file, $timestamp) {
    $lastModified=filemtime($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
    $gmt_mtime = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s T", $lastModified);
    header('ETag: "'.md5($timestamp.$file).'"');
    header('Last-Modified: '.$gmt_mtime);
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=3600');

    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'])) {
        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] == $gmt_mtime || str_replace('"', '', stripslashes($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'])) == md5($timestamp.$file)) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
            header("Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent");
            exit();
        }
    }
}
caching_headers ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], filemtime($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> If the client has performed a
>   conditional GET request and access is
>   allowed, but the document has not been
>   modified, the server SHOULD respond
>   with this status code. The 304
>   response MUST NOT contain a
>   message-body, and thus is always
>   terminated by the first empty line
>   after the header fields.

From - http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5

So, if you send a 304 don't send the body.

Comment: I know that and my question is not about this... My question is about WHEN do I send a 304...

Comment: Ah sorry, gotta slow down, = ]

Comment: I mean in which cases I send a 304. Example of answer I seek: "Send 304 when HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE present and match your last modified date AND when HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH is present and match your ETags".

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.controlstyle.com/articles/programming/text/if-mod-since-php/) will answer all your questions on caching

I found that adding

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE:%{HTTP:If-Modified-Since}]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH:%{HTTP:If-None-Match}]
```

To the bottom of my htaccess file (below all rewriterule) worked.

Answer (score -3):

Why?

Having done a lot of research on the subject I found that conditional requests actually slow down a site. There are certain scenarios where that is not the case, but mapping to general usage patterns overall it results in lower throughput and less effective caching.

C.

Comment: Why would it slow down a site. I can't even imagine how it would slow it down (it you send proper cache headers)...

Comment: The short answer to that question is about 5 pages of text and graphs. I keep meaning to put it on the internet somewhere.....watch this space.

Comment: Would be interesting to see that :)