# 304 Not Modified issue

Tags: php, header, http-status-code-304

Sorry for the probably wrong title. I am writing some code to handle If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match requests as part of caching. Everything works perfect except for that PHP returns some content (an empty line) after the headers. The page content should be empty instead. The code that I am using is:

```
<?php
$lastmod = filemtime($f);
$etag = '"'.dechex($lastmod).'"';
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] == $last_mod || $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] == $etag) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
  header('Content-Length: 0');
  exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code didn't go through. Reattach?

Comment: Error here: http://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fameer1234567890.co.cc%2Ftest%2Ftest.php

Comment: do not add the Content-Length header on 304 responses (ref RFC 2616 sec 4.3)

Comment: @Hafthor - actually it's perfectly fine (if a little stupid) to send a positive content-length with a 304 as the response "is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields, regardless of the entity-header fields present in the message." See RFC 2616 section 4.4 item 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved this bug. Gzip was the culprit. Since I was gzipping the responses to If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match requests too, gzip was adding a few bytes (kind of a gzip header) to the response. Now I have stopped gzipping responses to If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match requests, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$last_modified = filemtime($f);
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE"])) {
    $expected_modified = strtotime(preg_replace('/;.*$/','',$_SERVER["HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE"]));
    if($last_modified <= $expected_modified) {
        header("HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: My issue is not with detecting or returning proper headers, but just about an empty line outputted by php after the headers.

Comment: Error here: http://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fameer1234567890.co.cc%2Ftest%2Ftest.php

Comment: Do you have a `register_shudown_function` set?

Comment: I do not have a register_shutdown_function in my code. Could it be set by my webhost. I am using 110mb.com

Comment: It could be that you've got some weird whitespace before your opening `<?php`. Look out for those. Also, make sure all of your files are in Unix EOL format (LF, not the Windows "CR" format). If all else fails, it's your host.

Comment: My file doesn't have any whitespaces or characters before <?php or after ?>. I do not have a BOM too and my file is in LF format. As you said, my best suspect is my host.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in [Answering HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE and HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000715/answering-http-if-modified-since-and-http-if-none-match-in-php)

Create new file caching_headers.php

```
<?php
function caching_headers($file,$timestamp){
    $gmt_mtime=gmdate('r', $timestamp);
    header('ETag: "'.md5($timestamp.$file).'"');
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])||isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'])){
        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']==$gmt_mtime||str_replace('"','',stripslashes($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']))==md5($timestamp.$file)){
            header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
            exit();
        }
    }
    header('Last-Modified: '.$gmt_mtime);
    header('Cache-Control: public');
}
?>
```

and add this in all php files that you would like to cache:

```
<?php
include('caching_headers.php');
caching_headers($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'],filemtime($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
?>
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, my issue is not with detecting or returning proper headers, but just about an empty line outputted by php after the headers.

Comment: @Ameer - Maybe use `exit;` instead `exit();`.