# memcache a static front page in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

The class that writes out my static front page is given below. Google suggests memcaching static pages for better performance, but I'm lost as to how to go about doing this. Any suggestions?

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'index.html'

    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.write (template.render (path, {}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memcaching? Are you sure? You will not get any performance improvements, since it's just template rendering. Anyway, you can do this like described below.

```
from google.appengine.api import memcache

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'index.html'

    rendered = memcache.get('static_%s' % q)
    if rendered is None:
        path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
        rendered = template.render (path, {})
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.write(rendered)
```

The better way is to use client side caching like adding Last-Modified and eTag headers.
Some information about how to output 304 Not Modified you can find here: [Send a "304 Not Modified" for images stored in the datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750889/send-a-304-not-modified-for-images-stored-in-the-datastore)

Comment: When would memcaching be recommended?

Comment: When you get your data from datastore or external server using urlfetch. Memcache is about 10 times faster than datastore reads. But rendering static template is very fast.